# ionic 5 - users mentions

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4

I have Ionic-5 (angular 9) App with users chat,
i want to add mentions functionality to the ion-textarea,

its need to be something like Whatsup, twitter ,Facebook
when user typing '@' or '#' its will open dropdown with the users list with names and avatars,
and when continue typing the list will be filtered and show the relevant users.
when click on user from the list the keyboard stay opened and its name will be add to the textarea

is there ionic5/angular9 recommended libraries for mentions?
or should i have to write it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [angular-material-mentions](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/angular-material-mentions). Its quite simple and easy to use.

Checkout the demo [here](http://dmacfarlane.github.io/angular-mentions/?spm=a2c6h.14275010.0.0.9b3d7a80yOURXX). It was bsaed on [ment.io](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io)

EDIT:

Here are few more recommended libs

- [Angular mentions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mentions?file=package.json)

Comment: thanks Athif, i tried it, but its seems that are few problems with the integration with ionic like the dropdown is not append to body so its covered by others elements , and when you select item in the dropdown the selected item not added to the ion-textarea.
do you have more recommended libraries?